# How to create a clipping display window area without using an iframe or a library?

Tags: javascript, css, html, mask

I have a project that contains a bordered div where I would like to dynamically display some other div elements that represent visualized data points.  I have no trouble creating the elements and positioning them using javascript, but I'm now trying to keep them confined within the "display div."  I've looked into some clipping and masking ideas out there, but I'm not sure it's applicable (a lot of them deal with actual images - here, I'm not).  Below is a simplified representation of the page I'm building:

CSS:

```
#info {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#display {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#data {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background:green;
    left:70px;
    top:30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
Div Window Test<br>
<br>
<div id="info">Info Sidebar<br></div>
<div id="display">
    <div id="data"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a black-bordered display area, and a floating green circular-shaped  element to represent a data point drawn inside the display.  As shown, the data point div is partly outside the display.  There will be many, many data points of varying size AND location - some well inside the display, and some outside (and even some past the browser window).  What I would like to is somehow constrict/mask the data points to only show what's rendered within the display div boundaries.  Is there a simple way to do this using CSS or a mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

In below sample I added `position: relative;` to have your absolute positioned children relate to the `#display` element and `overflow: hidden;` to cut off any overflowed parts.

```css
#info {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#display {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;              /*  added  */
  overflow: hidden;                /*  added  */
}

#data {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:100px;
  background:green;
  left:70px;
  top:-30px;
}
```

```html
Div Window Test<br>
<br>
<div id="info">Info Sidebar<br></div>
<div id="display">
    <div id="data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! So simple a solution; this works with only a minor adjustment to calculating the element coordinates.  Thanks!  :)